# Como hacer que en este cronómetro, los segundos empiecen desde cero

Tags: javascript, jquery

Muy buenas, llevo tiempo dándole vueltas a este código y no se bien como manejarlo.
Esta función se llama una vez por segundo en un interval y compara dos fechas, fecha inicial con la fecha actual. El problema que tengo es que este cronómetro no empieza con los segundos a 00 empieza con 00:00:34 por ejemplo. o 00:00:46. Necesito que la primera vez que se llama a la función, el div al que se le pasan las horas minutos y segundos sea 00:00:00 y al segundo cuando se la llame sea 00:00:01 y así irá sumando pero partiendo desde 00.

```
  Function tiempoTicado(fecha,org){
    const myDatetime = fecha;
    const splitString = myDatetime.split(" ");//Se separa la cadena a partir del espacio entre la fecha y la hora
    const splitDate = splitString[0].split("/");//Se separan los elementos de la fecha
    const splitTime = splitString[1].split(":");//Se separan los elementos de la hora
    //Con los elementos separados, y para tener más orden y claridad, se puede asignar cada valor a variables cuyos nombres sean fáciles de identificar.
    //Enseguida, tendrás que restarle una unidad al valor del mes, esto debido a que el objeto Date de JavaScript trabaja con los meses de una manera similar a como lo hacen los arreglos y sus índices; es decir, empezando por el cero, lo cual quiere decir que, por ejemplo, el mes dado como 6, será interpretado como el séptimo. Asimismo, como el formato de la fecha es de cuatro dígitos, tendrás que completar la parte faltante. Esto puedes hacerlo concatenando el 20 con el valor de la variable del año.
    const day = splitDate[0]; //EL dia
    const month = splitDate[1] - 1;//El mes
    const year = `20${splitDate[2]}`;//El año
    const hours = splitTime[0];
    const minutes = splitTime[1];
    //Ya con todos los valores separados y formateados, puedes construir un objeto de fecha:
    const finalDatetime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
    const realDatetime = new Date(); //La fecha y hora del sistema
    //Finalmente, solo quedará realizar la resta de forma directa y dividir el resultado, dado en milésimas de segundo, entre el producto de 60 por 1000, esto debido a que se requiere transformar las milésimas de segundo a segundos y estos a minutos. Además de ello, puedes usar la función parseInt() para que el resultado mostrado no contenga la parte decimal:
    var diff = Math.abs(finalDatetime - realDatetime);
    var segundos = pad(Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60));
    var minutos = pad(Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60));
    
    /*
    if(org==2){
        if(minutos>19){
            audio.play();
        }
        if(segundos>58){
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
        }
    }*/

    

    var horas = pad(Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    $("#tiempo").text(horas +":"+minutos+":"+segundos);
    
    
    
}




function pad(val) { 
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
}


// Función para detener el intervalo
function detenerIntervalo() {
    var interval = sessionStorage.getItem(interval);
    clearInterval(interval);
}


function comienzaIntervalo(fecha,org){
    
    
    return setInterval(function() {
    tiempoTicado(fecha,org);
  }, 1000);
    
}
```

Comment: Es por el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse la función TiempoTicado. Intenta obtener la fecha actual, llamas a esta funcion y obtienes otra vez la fecha actual y la resta con la fecha primera para ver cuanto tiempo tardas en ejecutar la función, y le pones al interval 1000-el calculo anterior

Comment: Hola Lorenzo, lo que tienes es un error conceptual, **Math.abs( finalDatetime - realDatetime )** estás restando una fecha que no tiene segundos (osea segundos = "0"), la que recibes como parámetro,  con la fecha actual, traída del sistema, que tiene segundos y no necesariamente están en cero, por lo que tienes una probabilidad de 1/60 de obtener un comienzo en cero, para que funcione, debes quitarle a la fecha del sistema, los segundos... si no me equivoco!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un pequeño problema conceptual con [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), la primera ejecución se realiza una vez pasado el primer intervalo, en tu caso luego de haber transcurrido el primer segundo.

Ejemplo

```js
let Now;

function start(){
  Now = new Date();
  setInterval(intervalo,1000);
}

function intervalo(){
  const delta = new Date() - Now;
  console.log(delta + " milisegundos");
}

start();
```

Entonces **el cero no te lo va a mostrar nunca**, a menos que lo coloque tu "manualmente" antes de iniciar el `setInterval`

Aquí un ejemplo completo y comentado:

```js
let Now;

function start(){
  console.log(display(0)); //mostramos 00:00:00 "manualmente"
  Now = new Date(); //seteamos el punto de referencia
  setInterval(intervalo,1000); //comienza la iteración
}

function intervalo(){
  const delta = new Date() - Now; //milisegundos transcurridos
  console.log(display(Math.floor(delta/1000))); //pasamos a segundos y mostramos por consola
}

function display(seg){ //función para pasar los segundos transcurridos a formato HH:mm:ss
  return new Date(0,0,0,0,0,seg).toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
}

start();
```